# Timeout exception and 'Cannot access destination table #name' on bulk.WriteToServer(readerTabel) with small timeout /SQL wait time/block

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlbulkcopy

I have a problem with SqlBulkCopy that sometimes(pretty often) i get a timeout error and an sql error 'Cannot access destination table #temp'.

My timeout on bulkcopy is 5 seconds. After further investigation with SQL Profiler i found that on this specific server i have a wait time on the query generated by SQLBulkCopy (more than 5 seconds) so this is why i get the timeout and the error.

My SQL Server knowledge are basic so i tried what i knew.

So i drafted a test case on the SSMS on the same server and the problem was there. I get results from 0-20 seconds. Its obviously that on this specific server is a problem but i can't find it. I say this 'specific server' becouse on others works just fine , the query is instant even with 60-100 columns.

I saw that on this server i have a large number of Temporary Tables generated by sql with names #RANDOMSTRING. Can this be the problem? Or what else?

```
create table #something 
( Id int, Name nvarchar(max)
, a1 int
, a2 int
, a3 int
, a4 int
, a5 int
, a6 int
, a7 int
, a8 int
, a9 int
, a10 nvarchar(max)
, a11 nvarchar(max)
, a12 nvarchar(max)
, a13 nvarchar(max)
, a14 nvarchar(max)
, a15 nvarchar(max)
, a16 nvarchar(max)
, a17 nvarchar(max)
, a18 nvarchar(max)
, a19 nvarchar(max)
, a20 nvarchar(max)
)

--this query is generated by SQLBulkCopy
--this is where the block/wait time occurs.
select @@trancount; 
SET FMTONLY ON select * from #something SET FMTONLY OFF;
exec tempdb..sp_tablecollations_100 N'.[#something]';

rollback tran
```